# Using Word Embeddings to find similarity between documents with certain words having more weight

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, similarity, word2vec

Using Word embeddings ,I am calculating the similarity distance between 2 paragraphs where distance between 2 paragraphs is the sum of euclidean distances between vectors of 2 words ,1 from each paragraph.
The more the value of this sum, the less similar 2 documents are-

How can I assign prefernce/weights to certain words while calculating this similarity distance.

Comment: You might want to flesh out your question a bit more - it is quite unclear what you tried and where your exact problem is. SO does not code for you, it helps you fix your code. The downvotes you are collecting and the fact that this might be put on hold is feedback from the community that your question is not answerable in the current form. Providing the code you wrote might help. Reading [JonSkeet: writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) might give you ideas on how to improve you post.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've improvised your own paragraph-to-paragraph distance measure based on doing (lots of?) word-to-word distances.

Are you picking the words for each word-to-word comparison randomly, and doing it a lot to find the overall difference?

One naive measure that works better-than-nothing is to average all words in a paragraph to get a single vector for the paragraph. You could conceivably  overweight words there quite easily by assigning each word a weight, default `1.0` (for normal average), but larger to overweight words.

Another more sophisticated comparison based on word-vectors is "Word Mover's Distance" - it essentially considers each word to be a "pile of meaning", and then finds the minimal pairwise "moves" to tranform one paragraph (as a bag-of-words) to another. (It's available in Python gensim as `wmdistance()`, and other libraries.) It's quite a bit more expensive to calculate, though, especially as a function of text word count.